# Is there a way to colorize output per stream from a program

Tags: bash, colors

I'm looking for a method to have bash colorize the output from a command based on what stream it was written to the terminal from. Is there any way to get it to colorize per stream?

Like for example

```
stdout -> regular color
stderr -> red
program created streams that write to the terminal -> blue
```

Answer (score 0):

While not identical to your requirements, this earlier question would be worth a read, where someone wanted to differentiate stdout/stderr by color.

[How to set font color for STDOUT and STDERR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841143/how-to-set-font-color-for-stdout-and-stderr)

Answer (score 0):

There's:

https://github.com/sickill/stderred

or you can do it from bash with something like:

```
rederror() { (tput setaf 1; cat ; tput sgr0) >&2; }
#Example
someCommand() { echo normal; echo error >&2; }
someCommand 2> >( rederror )
```

I don't think you can color non-stdout streat that go to the terminal blue from bash. It should be possible with that approach that stderred is using (but I think it only colors stderr).

Comment: The rederror does not seem to work with any consistency. I wrote a short cpp program that writes out on the various streams avaible to it using differint methods and testing it several times there was varying results. [gist](https://gist.github.com/HSchmale16/cd630ba49e9a28699d60)